# I cant't recive data from firestore with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have used the AngularFireList from @angular/fire/database to get data from firestore while the firestore contains data and I can't get any data from it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Customer } from '../shared/customer.model'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

customersRef: AngularFireList<any>;    // Reference to Student data list, its an Observable
customerRef: AngularFireObject<any>;   // Reference to Student object, its an Observable too


// Inject AngularFireDatabase Dependency in Constructor
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

getCustomersList() {
   this.customersRef = this.db.list('customers');
   return this.customersRef;
}


 getCustomer(id: string) {
   this.customerRef = this.db.object('customers/' + id);
   return this.customerRef;
}}
```

[image: this is my firestore database]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use http calls in angular on observable object or method you need to use the .subscribe() method, in your code:

```
getCustomersList() {
   this.db.list('customers').subscribe(customers => {
      this.customersRef=costumers;
      console.log(consumers) //too se the data recived
    });
   return this.customersRef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store values in declarative way in service.
You can just return

```
getCustomersList(): Observable<AngularFireList<any>> {
   return this.db.list('customers');
}


 getCustomer(id: string): Observable<AngularFireObject<any>> {
   return this.db.object('customers/' + id);
}
```

In component or another abstraction when you want to use this stream you can use

```
const customer$ = this.service.getCustomer();
customer$.subscribe((customer)=>console.log(customer))
```

or in html template

```
<div>{{customer$ | async}}
```

but you neet create field `customer$: Observable<AngularFireObject<any>> = service.getCustomer();`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated the code it returns me this problem:
Type 'AngularFireList<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<AngularFireList<any>>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 mor

Comment: Please show your whole code on Stackblitz. The error you encountered means that probably you use Observable as AngularFireList without subscription. It's hard to guess where :(